# In Animal Crossing New Leaf, how many items do I have to refurbish to get the silver refurbishing badge?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In my Animal Crossing New Leaf game, I have refurbished a lot of furniture **(The whole Exotic and Astro Sets to be exact)**.

I want to know how may items I have to refurbish to get the sliver badge for refurbishing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to refurbish 100 items to get the silver badge; 30 for bronze and 200 for gold.

Source: http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Badge